# Twilio Functions - Calling features

Tags: twilio

I am using twilio function for inbound call recording.

We have to ask multiple questions before start recording in a call.
We need to check with my database for every answers.

Is it possible in twilio functions to check every answers with my database ?

Sample Code :

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    let gather = twiml.gather({
    input: 'dtmf',
    finishOnKey: '#'
    });
    twiml.say("Please enter your code and press #");
    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Here how can i get user input number ? where i need to add query string
Please advice

Thanks

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Right now, it is not possible to install third party Node.js modules for Twilio Functions, as such it makes it quite hard to interact with most databases without their drivers. If your database is available over HTTP (like CouchDB) or has an HTTP API then you could use the regular Node http package, or the [included](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007737928-Building-apps-with-Twilio-Functions) [got module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) to access it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply .

Comment: No problem, hope the rest of your application goes well! :)

Comment: Can u show how to use callback url in twilio function

Comment: Check out the documentation here: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007737928-Building-apps-with-Twilio-Functions. It has examples for using the callback function.

Comment: Thanks for the doc. Can u specify how to get user input  in functions

Comment: Functions on Twilio are designed to be invoked by HTTP requests. You can send input as query string parameters in the URL or as the body of a POST request and you will get all the parameters in the `event` argument to the function.

Comment: Thanks i added event in query string of my URL and db check successfully done. But i didn't get response . in my PHP code i added

echo json_encode(array('status' => 1));

Comment: I'm not sure what PHP has to do with this. I'm confused about what you are asking right now. Perhaps it would be better to ask a new question rather than keep adding things to this one.

Comment: Please check this...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45348637/twilio-call-function-always-repeating-please-enter-your-id