# Twilio call function - Always repeating "Please enter your ID"?

Tags: twilio

Here's my code

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    let gather = twiml.gather({
        input: 'dtmf',
        finishOnKey: '#'
    });
    gather.play("Please enter your user ID");
    callback(null, twiml);

    var got = require('got');
    var requestPayload = event;
    got.post('http://www.test.com/test.php?test=' + JSON.stringify(requestPayload), {
            body: JSON.stringify(requestPayload),
            headers: {
                'accept': 'application/json'
            },
            json: true
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.body)
            callback(null, response.body);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            callback(error)
        })


};
```

I got successful response from url , but i need to ask second question . How to continue from here.

Thanks

Comment: What does the HTTP request do? What do you expect to receive back from it?

Comment: My HTTP request check whether user exist or not , if exist return 1 else 0 . 
Then there will be a second question

Comment: I got response successfully.SO there is no pblm in PHP response. After i got response i need to know how to add second question in this function . Thanks

Comment: I'm just answering. Give me a moment :)

Comment: What's the second question you need to ask?

Comment: Sorry :) ... I need to ask to enter their case ID

Comment: After entering their case ID ... i need to start record the call..Because there will be conversation after that. Thanks

Comment: I'm going to answer your current question and leave you to build the rest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you want to use just the one function for this, then you need it to do different things depending on whether the user has just called or if they have entered some digits.

I've rearranged your code a bit and left comments to guide you:

```
const got = require('got');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

  // We can set up our initial TwiML here
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  let gather = twiml.gather({
    input: 'dtmf',
    finishOnKey: '#'
  });

  if(event.Digits) {

    // The user has entered some digits to answer the question so we post to
    // your API and only callback when we get the results
    got.post('http://www.test.com/test.php', {
      body: JSON.stringify(event),
      headers: {
          'accept': 'application/json'
      },
      json: true
    })
    .then(function(response) {

      // Check the response and ask your second question here

      gather.say("Please enter your case ID.");
      callback(null, twiml);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Boo, there was an error.
      callback(error)
    });
  } else {

    // The user hasn't entered anything yet, so we ask for user ID
    gather.say("Please enter your user ID");
    callback(null, twiml);
  }
};
```

Let me know how that works for you. You might find that if you then need to do even more work that a single Function is not the best idea here and you should direct the user to a new Function to continue the call after the case ID is entered.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thank you :) will check and let u know

Comment: Good to hear! Good luck with the rest of the app!

Comment: Thank you , but still have doubts in redirect user to new function. It wont work

Comment: Is there any function avail to check how many times user input in a call..Thanks

Comment: Not out of the box, but you can add things to the URL to pass messages around to yourself.

Comment: Please check here , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351943/twilio-call-function-multiple-user-input