# Twilio Call Function - Multiple User input

Tags: twilio

Here's my code, tried to add more questions in a call when I pass test2 from test1, it won't redirect, it still goes to test1 because `event.digits` exist. How can I differentiate Digits to call to new function?

```
const got = require('got');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
 console.log(context);
    // We can set up our initial TwiML here
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    let gather = twiml.gather({
        input: 'dtmf',
        finishOnKey: '#'
    });

    if (event.Digits) {
        var requestPayload = event;
        // The user has entered some digits to answer the question so we post to
        // your API and only callback when we get the results
        got.post('http://test.com/test.php?test=' + JSON.stringify(requestPayload), {
                body: JSON.stringify(event),
                headers: {
                    'accept': 'application/json'
                },
                json: true
            })
            .then(function(response) {
               test(context,event,callback,twiml,gather);


            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                // Boo, there was an error.
                callback(error)
            });
    } else {

        // The user hasn't entered anything yet, so we ask for user ID
        gather.play('Please enter user ID');
        callback(null, twiml);
    }
};

function test2(context,event,callback,twiml,gather){
  twiml.say("start recording");
  callback(null, twiml);
}

function test(context,event,callback,twiml,gather){

  // Check the response and ask your second question here
                gather.say("Please enter your case ID and then press star to continue.");
                callback(null, twiml);


        var requestPayload = event;
        // The user has entered some digits to answer the question so we post to
        // your API and only callback when we get the results
        got.post('http://test.com/test.php?test=' + JSON.stringify(requestPayload), {
                body: JSON.stringify(event),
                headers: {
                    'accept': 'application/json'
                },
                json: true
            })
            .then(function(response) {
               test2(context,event,callback,twiml,gather);


            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                // Boo, there was an error.
                callback(error)
            });


}
```

It won't redirect to `test2()` function. Is there any issue in my code? I need to know how to use functions. Is there any way to find how many user inputs in a single call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As I said in my previous question, to differentiate between answers you can start putting parameters in the URL. You don't need to redirect to a new function (I really meant a new Twilio Function, but we can do this all within one if that's going to be easier).

This time around I assumed the path for your Twilio Function was `/voice`. I use the [`action` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action) of the [`<Gather>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) to direct answers to the same Twilio Function, but add a parameter to tell which question we are on. You can extend this further yourself if you need, this is just an example:

```
const got = require('got');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

  // We can set up our initial TwiML here
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  if(event.Digits) {
    // We've answered a question, but which one?
    // We can set the current question in the URL, so let's retrieve the 
    // current question, or default to question 1.
    const currentQuestion = parseInt(event.currentQuestion, 10) || 1;
    let url, question;

    if (currentQuestion === 1) {
      // If it's question 1 we can do things like set the next question or
      // the URL to post the results to.
      url = 'http://test.com/question1';
      question = 'Enter your case ID';
    }  else if (currentQuestion == 2) {
      // If it's question 2 then we set different options, depending on what
      // you need.
      url = 'http://test.com/question2';
      question = 'What\'s the next question';
    } // This could go on.

    got.post(url, {
      body: JSON.stringify(event),
      headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json'
      },
      json: true
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      // When we get a response from the API request we then set up the next
      // Gather. This time we do so with an `action` attribute to point back
      // to this URL again, but with the currentQuestion incremented.
      const gather = twiml.gather({
        input: 'dtmf',
        finishOnKey: '#',
        action: `/voice?currentQuestion=${currentQuestion + 1}`
      });
      gather.say(question);
      callback(null, twiml);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Boo, there was an error.
      callback(error)
    });
  } else {

    // Our first Gather should setup an action to this URL with the 
    // current question set to 1.
    const gather = twiml.gather({
      input: 'dtmf',
      finishOnKey: '#',
      action: `/voice?currentQuestion=1`
    });
    // The user hasn't entered anything yet, so we ask for user ID
    gather.say("Please enter your user ID");
    callback(null, twiml);
  }
};
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thank you ... Will check and let u know :) Thanks for ur time

Comment: Error says "We are sorry , unknown error occured" , when answers to first question

Comment: Ok, I've broken something then. I didn't run this code myself, so it's up to you to debug I'm afraid. Have I given you enough to play with?